# Drupal form - Popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to show some forms in my Drupal Website in a popup or accordion. I have tried popup module but it shows only for viewing nodes and not adding/editing. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this module help you  [Modal forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with https://drupal.org/project/popup_forms, but you need to do some programming in order to apply it (i.e. it can't be just configured via admin interface).

Comment: The sample code is provided on the module page @drupal.org.

Comment: @CodeYourDream Have you tried ctools_automodal module? It has an admin ui module as well. Very easy to use for a beginner like me. Good thing is that you can make any link or form modal. There is one problem, it does not update the view in realtime. You have to refresh the page.

Comment: @CodeYourDream I saw a video about popups api. I really want that module, but it not available for D7. I did not see any other module providing same functionality. There are some modules, but they are different

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion `Popups API` is a very good module.You could show the necessary contents that suites your purpose .It is quite easy to use.I think you just need to read the documentation.If you really change this module there are other modules available like `Modal forms`,`Modal Frame API`,`colorbox`, `Chaos tool suite` etc.You can find a lot of modules needed for your purpose. The following links might help you:

https://drupal.org/project/colorbox

https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms

https://drupal.org/project/modalframe

Comment: Unfortunately Popups API has not been updated in 4 years and is not actually available for Drupal 7, and this question is actually tagged as being Drupal 7 specific.